# How to alter a regex to be non-greedy (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to replace `var` tags with an attribute so they are wrapped in square brackets

`data.replace(/<var .*?="">(\d+)<\/var>/ig, '[[[$1]]]');`

but this will not work if there are multiple `var` tags. For example,

`<var id-0=""></var> responds <span id-1="">in <var num="">1</var> days</span>`

will result in

`[[[1]]] days</span>`

but the result I need is

`<var id-0=""></var> responds <span id-1="">in [[[1]]] days</span></strong>`

Comment: so `<var id-0="">` shouldn't be replaced ?

Comment: No because it doesn't have contents inside the tags

Comment: but can `id` actually have a content inside ? otherwise `<var num="">(\d+)<\/var>` would work fine I think

Comment: @moped, it can have content inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using this **`<var [^=]*="">(\d+)<\/var>`**

[**regex101** - 1](https://regex101.com/r/tR3aH1/1)

---

in case there would be more than one attribute or the attribute has value like `num="something"` then the above wouldn't work, instead, use this **`<var( [^=]*="[^"]*")*>(\d+)<\/var>`** with **`[[[$2]]]`** for substitution.

[**regex101** - 2](https://regex101.com/r/tR3aH1/4)

Answer (score 1):

Change the `.*?` to be `[^=">]*?`. Even though it isn't greedy, you are allowing it to capture far too much.